# How to navigate between two local HTML pages in oracle maf

Tags: oracle, maf

Is there any samples to navigate between local HTML pages using JavaScript in the oracle MAf.

Also is there any link available for writing business logic using JavaScript in Oracle MAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Work.Make sure that you keep your HTML pages in same folder.

```
function call() 
{
location.href = "untitled2.html";
}
```

Comment: How to include external css and js in oracle MAF Local HTML.

Comment: Use script to add javascript  <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/myjs.js"></script>

Comment: How to call feature(gotoFeature(featureId)) via javascript in Local HTML.

Comment: Check this document http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf210/mobile/develop-maf/appx-maf-javascript.htm#ADFMF23898